# Using AWS SDK functions in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to use AWS Lambda to restart an app server in an elastic beanstalk instance.

After extensive googling and not finding anything, I finally found an article that I have now lost that described how to do what I want. I used it to set up a Lambda function and an EventBridge cron schedule to run the function. Looking at my the cloudwatch logs for the eventbridge, I can see the function is successfully running. However, it is definitely not restarting my app server. When I use the console button to restart, the data I pulled in with another cron gets updated and I can see the date on my main page update. This does not happen when the lambda function runs, though it should.

Here is my function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const eb = new AWS.ElasticBeanstalk({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
const params = {
    EnvironmentName: 'my-prod-environment'
};

eb.restartAppServer(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        return err;
    }
    else {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
});
};
```

The logs, unfortunately, tell me nothing. Despite the console.log statement, no error or data appears in my logs, so I don't know if the function is even completing. Does anyone have any idea why this won't work?

Comment: You should add a `console.log` before calling `eb.restartAppServer` and before exiting the handler function. That way you would know for sure what was happening. Find out how long the EB server restart should take, and make sure that your Lambda lives for at least that long (the default timeout is low). Also, consider using the `.promise()` variants of AWS SDK calls so you can await results.

Comment: If you're using async functions you can probably use an `await eb.restartAppServer().promise()`